# Plotly zerolines at different levels on double axis plot

Tags: r, graph, data-visualization, plotly

I'm trying to overlay a line chart and bar chart in plotly (with a vertical line designating an important date) and I'm encountering this issue where the two zero lines are offset instead of on the same line. I've tried messing around with the `overlaying = 'y'` option within `layout` and tried changing the order of the three `trace` components but nothing seems to help. Any ideas how to fix? Below is my code with dummy data:

(Also, bonus points if you can fix my legend-overlapping-y2axis issue)

```
date <- seq(as.Date("2015/6/1"), by = "month", length.out = 19) 
wires_mnth <- c(rep(0,8),100000,750000,1200000,2500000,3100000,5500000,7500000,8000000,9900000,11300000,11000000)
wires_cnt <- c(rep(0,8),100,200,250,325,475,600,750,800,1000,1150,1200)
data <- data.frame(date, wires_mnth)

plot_ly(data) %>%
add_trace(x = ~date, y = ~wires_cnt, type = 'bar', name = 'Wires Count', 
    yaxis = 'y2', opacity = .5) %>%
add_trace(x = ~date, y = ~wires_mnth, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', name 
    = 'Monthly Wires') %>%
add_trace(x = c(2016,2016), y = c(0, 12000000), type = 'scatter', mode = 
    "lines", name = 'Sanctions Removed') %>%

layout(title = 'Monthly Aggregate Wire Transfers to Iran',
     xaxis = list(title = ''),
     yaxis = list(side = 'left', title = 'Wire Amounts (USD)', showgrid = 
         FALSE, zeroline = FALSE),
     yaxis2 = list(side = 'right', overlaying = 'y', title = 'Wires Count', 
        showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE)
     )
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add [`rangemode='nonnegative'`](https://plot.ly/r/reference/#layout-yaxis-rangemode) to your `layout` or specify the [`range`](https://plot.ly/r/reference/#layout-yaxis-range) manually via `range=list(0, max(wires_mnth)`.

For your bonus question, you can set the [x-position](https://plot.ly/r/reference/#layout-legend-x) of the legend, e.g.
`legend = list(x = 1.2)`

[image]

Comment: The plotly wizard!